# Escaping special characters for SQL Server 2005 while using COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, coalesce

OK, so I am trying to coalesce some records from a database

```
declare @selectlist varchar(max)

SELECT  @selectlist = COALESCE(@selectlist + ',[' + listitem + ']','['+ listitem +']')
FROM    (select distinct listitem from Project#lists  where listitem <> '') X
ORDER BY listitem
```

in order to use them in a PIVOT in SQL Server 2005. The problem is that the data has all sorts of weirdness in it...single quotes, brackets, %s, {'s and who knows what else.  Is there an EASY way to escape them all, or do I have to do a replace for everything?

(I thought about writing an assembly to do it with a regular expression, but I have to give this to a customer who may or may not have the need/desire to set this up)

Comment: Why would you need to escape single quotes, percentage signs, braces? If you're using brackets as your delimiter, you should only need to escape the closing bracket, and say that any other character isn't special. Or are you going to use the result in some way where you have no control of which characters mean what? Admittedly I'm unfamiliar with the pivot you mention, but looking it up, it doesn't seem to split strings at all, so you must mean something different from what I found.

Comment: thanks for the answer, hwd, but as I have only about 2 hours experience with pivot than you, specifying non-numeric values as columns for a pivot is fraught with peril...the biggest one that the column names are bare, and not quoted as strings (as I am used to).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)?  If you need more extensive modification than that I'm not sure if there is an intrinsic function that will do this for you.

Comment: thanks for the help, but quotename doesnt work either...I fear i am going to have to escape things individually.